# Coffeescript - Iterate through object's keys/values - return sorted array

Tags: coffeescript

I have an object with keys representing country shortcodes and values representing a count. I would like to iterate through this object and return an array of countries with the highest counts. I'm new to Coffeescript and unsure of the most elegant way to handle this. Any help is most appreciated. Thanks!

With the below data as an example I would like for the array to return `['AU', 'US', 'BR', 'CN', 'IN']`

```
vacation_spots = {
  AU: 3,
  BR: 2,
  CF: 1,
  CN: 2,
  IN: 2,
  MX: 1,
  SD: 1,
  TD: 1,
  TM: 1,
  US: 3
}

get_top_5(vacation_spots)

get_top_5 = (items) ->
    for k, v of items
    # ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using vanilla JS Array methods:

```
get_top_5 = (items) ->
  codes = (k for k of items)
  sortedCodes = codes.sort (a, b) -> items[b] - items[a]
  sortedCodes[...5]
```

You can compress it all into one expression like `(k for k of items).sort((a, b) -> items[b] - items[a])[...5]` but i think separating each step reads a bit better.

The sort step sorts the country codes by their value on the `items` object; it uses the [`Array::sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, which expects a comparator function that takes two arguments and returns an integer. If you have Underscore.js included, i'd recommend using [`_.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy), which uses comparator function that just takes one argument and returns a comparable object:

```
sortedCodes = _.sortBy codes, (code) -> -items[code]
```

**Edit**: Also, instead of `(k for k of items)` you can use `Object.keys(items)` (beware, IE <9 will not support it) or `_.keys(items)`, both of which will compile to much more compact JS code than the loop.

Comment: did you mean `sortedCodes[...5]` ?

Comment: @Kyle Yes! Thanks for noting that :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#Use some underscore helper methods
_ = require "underscore"

vacation_spots = {
  AU: 3,
  BR: 2,
  CF: 1,
  CN: 2,
  IN: 2,
  MX: 1,
  SD: 1,
  TD: 1,
  TM: 1,
  US: 3
}

#use _.keys to get a list of country codes
ranked = _.sortBy _.keys(vacation_spots), (spot) ->
  #Sort them by their negated counts
  -vacation_spots[spot]

#Slice off the top 5
console.log ranked.slice(0, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [this out](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3avacation_spots%20=%0A%20%20AU%3a%203%0A%20%20BR%3a%202%0A%20%20CF%3a%201%0A%20%20CN%3a%202%0A%20%20IN%3a%202%0A%20%20MX%3a%201%0A%20%20SD%3a%201%0A%20%20TD%3a%201%0A%20%20TM%3a%201%0A%20%20US%3a%203%0A%0Aget_top_5%20=%20%28items%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%28%5Bk,%20v%5D%20for%20k,%20v%20of%20items%29.sort%20%28a,%20b%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20b%5B1%5D%20-%20a%5B1%5D%0A%20%20.slice%280,%205%29.map%20%28n%29%20-%3E%20n%5B0%5D%0A%0Aalert%20get_top_5%28vacation_spots%29%20#%20%22AU%22,%20%22US%22,%20%22BR%22,%20%22CN%22,%20%22IN%22)

```
vacation_spots =
  AU: 3
  BR: 2
  CF: 1
  CN: 2
  IN: 2
  MX: 1
  SD: 1
  TD: 1
  TM: 1
  US: 3

get_top_5 = (items) ->
  ([k, v] for k, v of items).sort (a, b) ->
    b[1] - a[1]
  .slice(0, 5).map (n) -> n[0]

get_top_5 vacation_spots # ["AU", "US", "BR", "CN", "IN"]
```